# how to click element with similar element details on button with span using Protractor typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, protractor, webautomation

[image]

Need your help on creating a protractor typescript code, how do i click one of this button? it has _ngcontent class and span class, does anyone have an idea how to do this? code on the site is:

```
<form _ngcontent-c34 novalidate class="ng-untouched ng-unreal ng-valid">
    <atx-create-license-act-main _ngcontent-c34 _nghost-c36>
       <button _ngcontent-c36 color="accent" mat-raised-button class="mat-raised-button mat-accent">
           <span class="mat-button-wrapper">Add License</span>
           <div class="mat-button-droped mat-droped" matdrop></div>
           <div class="mat-button-focus-overlay"></div>
        </button>
    </atx-create-license-act-main>
</form>
<form _ngcontent-c34 novalidate class="ng-untouched ng-unreal ng-valid">
    <atx-create-license-act-main _ngcontent-c34 _nghost-c36>
       <button _ngcontent-c36 color="accent" mat-raised-button class="mat-raised-button mat-accent">
           <span class="mat-button-wrapper">Add License</span>
           <div class="mat-button-droped mat-droped" matdrop></div>
           <div class="mat-button-focus-overlay"></div>
        </button>
    </atx-create-license-act-main>
</form>
```

i've tried the following code below, i can't seem to make it work...

```
clickdone = element.all(by.cssContainingText('.mat-button-wrapper','Add License')).get(0);
clickdone = element.all(by.css('button.mat-raised-button.mat-accent')).get(1);
clickdone = element(by.cssContainingText('span.mat-button-wrapper','Add License'));
clickdone = element.all(by.cssContainingText('button.mat-raised-button.mat-accent','Add License')).get(0);
```

then performed...

```
clickdone.click();
```

none of them seem to work.. and an error says.. "Failed: element not interactable".
What does it mean? i stuck on this, any idea how to do this?

Comment: Do you want to click both or just one ?

Comment: i want to click just one

Comment: Did you try assigning an id to one button `id='b_1'` and the go `element(by.id('b_id')).click()` ?

Comment: button does not have an id based on the sites code

Comment: Why do you use _element.all_?

Comment: i used element.all, because it has 2 or more element that has the same name, and so i can have two unique items to differentiate from the others, and to be able to work .get() functionality

Comment: You should ask developer of this button, why there is 2 identical buttons...

Comment: somehow it is not similar, it has a border name outside its buttons
https://imgur.com/tSimCTl

Comment: Why the code of "Open" and "Closed" spans is truncated? You need to use it to make unique locator, using XPath

Comment: Also, don't click on <span>, click on <button> instead.
element.all(by.css('button')).get(1).click()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with below one

```
addLicense = element.all(by.css('button>span.mat-button-wrapper');

browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(addLicense.get(0)), 5000); 
addLicense.get(0).click();
```

Chnage the index based on the button you wish to click.

Hope it helps you